# Проблема с записью аудио потока из интернета

Tags: android

Есть приложение, которое записывает аудио поток (радио) из интернета и сохраняет в память телефона. Приложение не мое и было достаточно большим, но я вытащила из него то что нужно и пытаюсь реализовать запись онлайн радио.

Проблема следующая: В классе `StreamRecorder` компилятор ругается на кусок кода, а именно на три строчки, которые я закомментировала. Если комментарии убрать то компилятор ругается на недостижимый код. Скорее всего по этой причине у меня проблема такая что если первый раз нажму кнопку "Запись", то начинается запись и когда нажимаю "Стоп", то запись заканчивается и создается файл, а вот когда второй раз нажимаю "Запись", то еще один файл не создается.

```
while (true) {
    int bytesRead = bis.read(chunk);
    if (bytesRead == -1 || isCancelled()) {
        bis.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
        connection.disconnect();
    } else {
        fileOutputStream.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
/*bis.close();
fileOutputStream.close();
connection.disconnect();*/
```

Весь класс StreamRecorder

```
public class StreamRecorder extends AbstractRecorder {
    private OnErrorListener onErrorListener;
    private StreamDownloadTask task;

    private class StreamDownloadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String filepath;
        String link;

        private StreamDownloadTask() {
        }

        public void setLink(String link) {
            this.link = link;
        }

        void setFilepath(String filepath) {
            this.filepath = filepath;
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if (this.link != null) {
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(this.link).openConnection();
                    connection.connect();
                    String contentType = connection.getContentType();
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(contentType) || contentType.startsWith(MimeTypes.BASE_TYPE_AUDIO)) {
                        String filetype = "mp3";
                        if (contentType.equals("audio/ogg")) {
                            filetype = "ogg";
                        } else if (contentType.equals("audio/wav") || contentType.equals("audio/x-wav")) {
                            filetype = "wav";
                        }
                        File file = new File(this.filepath + "." + filetype);
                        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                        byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
                        while (true) {
                            int bytesRead = bis.read(chunk);
                            if (bytesRead == -1 || isCancelled()) {
                                bis.close();
                                fileOutputStream.close();
                                connection.disconnect();
                            } else {
                                fileOutputStream.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
                            }
                        }
                        /*bis.close();
                        fileOutputStream.close();
                        connection.disconnect();*/
                    } else {
                        connection.disconnect();
                        if (StreamRecorder.this.onErrorListener != null) {
                            StreamRecorder.this.onErrorListener.onError(StreamRecorder.this);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if (StreamRecorder.this.onErrorListener != null) {
                        StreamRecorder.this.onErrorListener.onError(StreamRecorder.this);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public StreamRecorder(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void init() {
        this.task = new StreamDownloadTask();
        setState(State.INITIALIZED);
    }

    public void setDataSource(String dataSource) {
        this.task.setLink(dataSource);
    }

    public void setDataDestination(String destinationDir, String filename) throws IOException {
        File parentDirs = new File(destinationDir);
        if (parentDirs.isDirectory() || parentDirs.mkdirs()) {
            this.task.setFilepath(destinationDir + File.separator + filename);
            return;
        }
        throw new IOException();
    }

    public void prepare() {
    }

    public void start() {
        this.task.execute(new Void[0]);
        setState(State.RECORDING);
    }

    public boolean isRecording() {
        return state == State.RECORDING;
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.task.cancel(false);
        setState(State.STOPPED);
    }

    public void reset() {
        if (this.task.getStatus() != Status.FINISHED) {
            this.task.cancel(true);
        }
        this.task = new StreamDownloadTask();
    }

    public void setOnInfoListener(OnInfoListener listener) {
    }

    public void setOnErrorListener(OnErrorListener listener) {
        this.onErrorListener = listener;
    }

    public void release() {
        this.task.cancel(true);
        this.task = null;
        setState(State.IDLE);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageButton recordBtn;
    ImageButton recordStopBtn;
    AbstractRecorder recorder;
    Context context;

    String FILES_DIR = (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "MYRADIO/");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recordBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.recordBtn);
        recordStopBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.recordStopBtn);

        this.context = MainActivity.this;

        recordBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        recordStopBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.recordBtn:
                startRecord();
                return;
            case R.id.recordStopBtn:
                stopRecord();
                return;
        }
    }

    private void startRecord() {
        String record_from = "stream";
        if (canRecord(record_from)) {
            String filename = getRecordFilename();
            if (this.recorder == null) {
                if (record_from.equals("stream")) {
                    this.recorder = new StreamRecorder(this.context);
                }
            }
            this.recorder.init();
            this.recorder.setDataSource("http://91.207.59.26/a102");
            try {
                this.recorder.setDataDestination(FILES_DIR, filename);
                this.recorder.prepare();
                this.recorder.start();
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
                ignore.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopRecord() {
        if (this.recorder != null) {
            if (this.recorder.isRecording()) {
                this.recorder.stop();
                this.recorder.reset();
                this.recorder.release();
                this.recorder = null;
            }
        }
    }

    private String getRecordFilename() {
        String filename = "file_";
        return filename + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private boolean canRecord(String record_from) {
        boolean can_write_external_storage;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context, "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            can_write_external_storage = true;
        } else {
            can_write_external_storage = false;
        }
        boolean can_record_audio;
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context, "android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO") == 0) {
            can_record_audio = true;
        } else {
            can_record_audio = false;
        }
        if (can_write_external_storage && (!record_from.equals("mic") || can_record_audio)) {
            return true;
        }
        List<String> permissions = new ArrayList(2);
        if (!can_write_external_storage) {
            permissions.add("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
        }
        requestPermissions((String[]) permissions.toArray(new String[permissions.size()]), 1);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: У Вас нет выхода из цикла - по этому код за ним не достижим.

Comment: Как будет правильнее?

Comment: В условие внутри цикла добавить `break;`. А закомментированный код вообще-то должен быть в `finally`-блоке.

Comment: Добавила break в цикл, теперь записываются файлы размером в 1 КБ, сколько бы долго не длилась запись.

Comment: Вы добавили в блок `if` после `connection.disconnect();`?

Comment: Да именно туда.